# Strange core_cy module import error while running cx_freeze built python executable

Tags: python, centos6, cx-freeze

I am trying to export my Python script to a high performance cluster (running CentOS 6), while circumventing the need to install additional Python packages. I use a virtual CentOS 6 environment onto which I installed all the required packages to create an executable using `cx_freeze`, which I can then transfer to the cluster for execution.

I ran into some errors with `scipy` and `cx_freeze` that I now believe to be resolved (thanks to extensive documentation on this subject on StackOverflow).

However, I immediately got another error that I don't understand. I can not find any information on the supposed module that is missing, nor on the error itself, let alone in combination with `cx_freeze`.

The following error is generated when I try to run the executable:

`ImportError: No module named core_cy`

I use the following `setup.py` from the file to build the executable using cx_freeze:

```
import sys
import scipy

from os import path

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includefiles_list=[]
scipy_path = path.dirname(scipy.__file__)

includefiles_list.append(scipy_path)

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "include_files": includefiles_list}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None

setup(  name = "CD34Filter",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "CD34Filter Script",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("cd34_filter.py", base=base)])
```

I already tried adding the `"excludes": ["core_cy"]` option to `build_exe_options`. But that didn't do anything.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some additional research, I found out that `core_cy` is a module of the `skimage` module. I proceeded by including scikit-image into the package in the same manner I used to include the `scipy`. This resolved the error and now my executable runs great! Hope this will be of use to anyone else.

```
import sys
import scipy
import skimage

from os import path

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includefiles_list=[]
scipy_path = path.dirname(scipy.__file__)
skimage_path = path.dirname(skimage.__file__)

includefiles_list.append(scipy_path)
includefiles_list.append(skimage_path)

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "include_files": includefiles_list}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None

setup(  name = "CD34Filter",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "CD34Filter Script",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("cd34_filter.py", base=base)])
```